# Function to predict processing service overload

Tags: mathematical-modeling, machine-learning, order-statistics, regression-analysis

We have a black box that for each input request a, it outputs a computed response b.

The computation time for a given request varies in a stable way over time. Stable means here that it is still meaningful to use aggregating functions like average, max, moving average, ... etc. This variation can be imagined to be caused by internal changes to the black box that we can't observe independently.

But there is another potential, independently observable, parameter that can affect computation time, namely input pressure, or let's say number of inputs per seconds.

As any service, there is a limit of input pressure, capacity, after which the service will start drastically slowing down at each increase, let's call that a service overload.

Things we can measure here are, number of inputs per unit of time, number of outputs per unit of time, processing time for each input (and so averages, max, min of these).

The question is, can we design a "pressure filter" function that can predict that an overload is happening or going to happen?

Note: the black box can be capable of doing parallel computing, meaning that we can't rely on capacity_per_second = 1 / computation_time

Note2: We can't inject experimental input into the black box, we can only observe and measure on natural input

Note3: Natural input varies chaotically, it can be under the capacity of the black box

One thing I thought of is simply try to detect dependency between the increase of input pressure and the increase of processing_time, and call that an overload. Not sure though.

Another idea is to maintain a `normal_processing_time` calculated using a sliding average of `processing_time` and if `x` increase in input results in an increase of `x * normal_processing_time` to the previous `normal_processing_time` then an overload is happening.

Old description of the problem

> Let's say I have a black box that does some processing, it takes an
>   input, and gets out some output for that input.
>
> I have no prior information about how fast the processing per input
>   is, how many concurrent inputs it can process or what is its full
>   processing capacity.
>
> All what I can do is observe it from the outside, and without
>   interacting directly with it.
>
> The processing speed, and capacity can change over time, and it can
>   depend on multiple factors, like the input frequency (faster or slower
>   with more input frequency). It can also (less frequently) change its
>   characteristics with some internal factors (things inside the black
>   box that we can't independently observe).
>
> I need a function that would be able to predict a potential service
>   overload, based maybe on the history of the processing of this black
>   box.
>
> The question is basically, is whether it is possible to have a generic
>   smart "pressure filter", that has sensors or counters on both ends of
>   a black box. This filter will rejects inputs anytime it thinks the
>   service is not keeping up with its input. Is this filter even
>   conceivable, given that its error may result in its service never
>   being loaded to even its real capacity?
>
> I thought about using an [Exponential moving
>   average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) for input rate
>   and output rate, and subtract them to detect an overload. But this
>   won't work since sudden increase in input rate still causes a false
>   prediction.
>
> Another idea is to use the EMA for the processing time per input, but
>   it won't work either since the parallel processing can't be predicted
>   that way.
>
> Maybe Regression analysis could help here, but I am not sure.
>
> Maybe if we discover causality between the increase of the input
>   throughput and an abnormal increase of processing time per input, we
>   can conclude that an overload is happening. Or maybe simply an
>   abnormal increase of processing time per input alone should activate
>   the filter.
>
> Is there an obvious way for solving this that I am completely missing?

Comment: maybe the only way to know is measuring the (length of) the input queue, if it is increasing and beyond a certain treshold you are in trouble, also you can calculate an historical troughput time, the variation in the input load and so on, but more practically how do you define a service overload?

Comment: the problem is with determining the threshold.

A service overload is when we can have enough certainty (using maybe historical data) that the service won't be able to keep up with the input throughput. Like maybe rapidly and abnormally increasing queuing time.

Comment: I think you first need to model the problem more precicely, and which parameters are dependent and which are independent , and when an overload has occurs, before I can say anything more. (now it looks that an overload occurs when an input results in a late output, but is that the only overload?)

Comment: The question is basically, is whether it is possible to have a generic smart "pressure filter", that has sensors or counters on both ends of a black box.
This filter will rejects inputs anytime it thinks the service is not keeping up with its input.

Is this filter even conceivable, given that its error may result in its service never being loaded to even its real capacity?

Comment: The problem confuses me quite a bit. If the service has never had enough input, we can never really know its real capacity. Same goes for processing time, is 1 second too long? 1 hour? 1 day? Can historical data get us close knowing that the processing is not sequential (we can't simply divide available_time / processing_time)?

Comment: he you are the OP, you should provide those details :) , maybe you need to investigate the black box more (can you overload it? , can you injectinputs in the input stream and measure how long it takes for a result  to come out , to calculate the (average) processing time, and more like that) GOOD LUCK

Comment: maybe if we discover causality between the increase of the input throughput and an abnormal increase of processing time per input, we can conclude that an overload is happening.

Or maybe simply an abnormal increase of processing time per input alone should activate the filter.

Comment: The problem is that I can't inject input into it to make measurements, I can only observe and measure what is happening naturally.

Comment: @willemien thanks, your questions helped me advance in my analyses of the problem.

Comment: Think further about the problem and so , I will now ask the moderators to remove the question ( not enough detail, unanswerable) , feel free to repost when you have more details/ other questions GOOD LUCK

Comment: meaning that this is not a place where I can ask questions about understanding problems? is there a stack exchange community for that?

Comment: Hi Sadache, I think the question as asked does not contain enough information to get an clear answer,(I hope you can agree with that) I think you should think about what you nee frim where you are,  probably your question should be something like "how can I model this proces?" and give (much) more details, see http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask 
 (and add the mathematical modeling tag ) I did make a post on your question at the meta site see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13866/where-to-refer-to maybe some others have better ideas than me,  Good luck

Comment: This doesn't look like mathematical modeling to me at all. This looks more like a problem in regime of signal processing. Folks on the stackoverflow might have a better idea which SE community will have better expertise for this sort of problem.

Comment: @Willemien I agree. Actually I asked this question here because I suspect that the difficulty in the problem I am trying to solve is in the modelling. One of the answers that could have satisfied the question is "not solvable and here is why". Or "you need to give up A and B properties to make it solvable".

But it seems it's not the right community for the kind of exchange I was hoping. Mathematics is clearly not my domain, and I can try to make a formal description of my problem, but I am not sure I'd succeed alone.

Comment: Anyway, this discussion has cleared up some things to me, I will try to explore the problem further.

Comment: @Willemien I tried to structure my question better, do you think it improves it in anyway?

Comment: much better, now i can think of an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

At least there is been some more thinking going on :)

just some random remarks:

First of all you need to set some norms, what are allowable troughput times?

And then you have to implement some test that if the troughput time gets higher than say 80% of the allowable troughput time start squeezing the input.
(go to a "one out-one in "system or something like that)

Or more fancy, first collect all imputs, and only pass such an amount that the troughput times are within the limits stated.

maybe better you can also first on a lower level remove less interesting imputs. (what are the lost opportunity costs of a rejected imput, are the costs the same for every input, or are some imputs more valuable?)

Problem off course is that all this pre-proces testing adds time to the troughput time so the cure can be worse than the illness.

see still more details needed.

Also i was wondering how can you measure troughput times? 
is it because the imput is given in the output and you check the time between input and output?

under low traffic (normal) conditions, is the troughput for every input more or less equal or take some inputs (much) more time than others?

or do you have a list to check if an output passes that is in the list, if the last  why not directly pass the output back? (and make the whole syetem more efficient)

Comment: >> First of all you need to set some norms, what are allowable troughput times?


I guess you're referring to the allowable processing time. There is nothing like that specified. We can maybe infer a "normal" processing time from history (using sliding average) and compare to that.

I was thinking that if `x` more input is adding `x * normal_processing_time` then it might be that there is some waiting happening. This might be interpreted as service overload.

Comment: The ideas around how and which input to reject if an overload is detected are very interesting. But my focus in this question is to detect first the overload.

For measuring processing_time, let's say we can attach a timestamp to each input before we push it in, and the timestamp will be in the output.